# State Residency for tax purposes / substantial presence test

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax

I was a visitor to the US. With three trips I made during 2017 I met the substantial presence test and I became consequently resident for tax purposes for the entire 2017 as I arrived to the US on 12/22/2016.

So, I’ll file my return (form 1040) for the first time.

My question is: as I don’t have neither “domicile” in any State nor my “permanent” home in any, but in my country (Argentina, city of Buenos Aires), I don’t have to file any State tax form, do I?. I mean, I must file tax return at federal level but no at State level, must I?

Comment: Do you have enough income to need to file a tax return?

Comment: What states were you in? Each state's residency rules are different.